# iOS: How to remove UIViewController shadow changes as another UIViewController is being pushed/popped

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have two `UIViewController` objects with a white background color. When I push page A over page B through a `UINavigationController`, I notice that iOS is adding a shadow on page B during page transition. Similarly, when page A is being popped, page B reverts its shadow change slowly.

Is it possible to remove shadow animations during page push/pop actions?

I found [UINavigationController remove drop shadow when transitioning to another VC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719916/uinavigationcontroller-remove-drop-shadow-when-transitioning-to-another-vc) which is somewhat similar, but it seems to be about a drop shadow added to the edge of page A. Also, as one of the comments suggests, losing the ability to swipe back is not an option for me.

I'm on iOS 15.4 and would like to know if there is a way to disable shadows.

Comment: Do you want to keep the default alpha fade-out/-in, and the overlap? Or... do you want it to look like two side-by-side views sliding back and forth?

Comment: I'd like to keep the overlap but remove the alpha fade out/in. It actually looks like iOS is adding a dimming view on page B instead of animating its alpha.

Comment: You'll want to use a custom transition. This article should be a good place to start: [Simple, custom navigation transitions](https://ordinarycoding.com/articles/simple-custom-uinavigationcontroller-transitions/) -- note: this is not mine - just found it from quick searching. Took just a couple edits to disable the "fade" and keep the overlap...